# IOS Home press button event when IOS application not open

Tags: ios, swift

i want to develop security app on IOS (Apple) platform. now my requirement is to handle home button press event when application not open or not in foreground screen.

is there any way to handle home button event out of application??

Answer (score 1):

No as far as I am aware this is not feasible. Even with a enterprise controlled device - MDM etc. it is not possible.

Comment: can you provide any link related to your answer?

Comment: You can detect only when the app is alive, I have tried this in the past and failed. I have no links to show you.

Comment: is it possible if we use Gestures in background??